# .NET Core App - How to get build number at runtime

Tags: azure-devops, .net-core

I've got a .NET Core MVC app which is built using TFS online, and published to Azure using the Release management stuff in TFS online.  All very nice.

What I'd like to do is have my app display the build number somewhere.  Doesn't matter where...but for example in a WebAPI endpoint like /api/buildversion.

Can anyone help with how I can get the TFS build number at runtime?  When the app is packaged/published is there any file which contains the build number that I can access from the application?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, accepted!  And thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple way is that you can store the build number in a file (e.g. appsettings.json), then get this data in app code.

Appsettings.json sample code:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication1-ab933d83-8f4b-4024-9f3c-1aef5339a8f3;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
  "CodeVersion": {
    "Num": "#{MyBuildNumber}#"
  }
}
```

1. Install [Replace Tokens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)
2. Edit your build definition
3. Click Variables tab and add a variable. (Name: MyBuildNumber, Value:$(Build.BuildNumber))
4. Add Replace Tokens build step before build step

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, tried it and it works like a charm!  Many thanks!!

Comment: Struggling to find an answer to this question in the case that it is -not- on azure just using Visual Studio...

Comment: Use a standard. And don't place # tokens in your appsettings files.

Comment: I cannot get this to work at all, tried different approaches.

Answer (score 10):

There is an easier way than adding more plugins and libraries. If you are using the web/app deploy method, expand the File Transforms & Variables 
[image]

Assuming you want to update say a build number value in your appsettings.json

[image]

Then just update the variables setting in your release definition of VSTS 
[image]

Super easy. This is more or less the same steps in Octopus IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the Build Number in your application at compile time.

You can access the build number with $Build.BuildNumber or $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER depending on your environment. I usually write it as a variable into my ApplicationInfo.* with both the version and build number.

Comment: Makes sense!  Can you help with some details as I'm not an expert with Team Build.  I mean do I need a little PowerShell script, or what do I use to write into the application file?

Comment: Simply searching for this problem will yeald many results. Try something, and if you run into a problem raise additional questions...

Comment: Thanks!  @starain's answer looks like it's exactly what I'm after