# Exposing TFS buildnumber via an endpoint of .NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, tfs, asp.net-core-webapi

In a solution I have a .NET Core 2.2 WebAPI project (among other projects).
The solution has a corresponding build pipeline set up in TFS. Every TFS build has a build number, for example "20190615.15". What I would like to do is to expose this build number via an Web-API endpoint in order to fulfill maintaining and tracing purposes.

As a pre-solution I have managed to set the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attribute from the build pipeline, and with the following controller I can easily retrieve the desired build-number:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class VersionController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPut(Name = "version")]
    public Task<ApplicationVersion> Version()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new ApplicationVersion
        {
            Version = ReadVersionFromAssemblyInfo()
        });
    }

    private string ReadVersionFromAssemblyInfo()
    {
        return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
            .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
            .InformationalVersion;
    }

    public class ApplicationVersion
    {
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I have done is pretty easy:
First I introduced a new `ARG` called "VERSION_NUMBER" in the Dockerfile of the Web-API and set the `InformationalVersion` at the last publish step:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
ARG VERSION_NUMBER
WORKDIR /src
COPY SomeAPI/SomeAPI.csproj SomeAPI/
RUN dotnet restore SomeAPI/SomeAPI.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/SomeAPI
RUN dotnet publish SomeAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app -p:InformationalVersion=$VERSION_NUMBER
```

Then in the docker-compose.yml file I set the same `arg`:

```
services:
  someapi:
    image: someApi:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SomeAPI/Dockerfile
      args:
        VERSION_NUMBER: ${VERSION_NUMBER}
```

And finally in the Docker-Compose task of TFS build I set the above-mentioned argument:
[image: Docker-Compose task of TFS build]

It works like charm, and if I access my endpoint `https://somedomain.com/api/version` then I get a json back with the desired build-number.

The issue is that in my solution I reuse/leverage the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attribute, but I would like to have this attribute set with the proper version number (f.e.: 1.0.1). So eventually the `https://somdomain.com/api/version` endpoint would return the a .json like:

```
{
    "Version": "1.0.1",
    "BuildNumber": "20190615.15"
}
```

What is the best way to expose the build-number (coming from TFS build) via a Web-API endpoint? Is it possible to set a custom property (xml tag) in the .csproj file, therefore I can use the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` for the intended purpose? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully figured how to solve my issue. There are two good approaches to do it:

**First approach:** Introduce a custom .csproj property which can be accessed in run-time. First create a property class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A run-time-accessible property specified in .csproj file in order to store the build-number of the CI build-pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
    public sealed class BuildNumberAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public BuildNumberAttribute(string buildNumber)
        {
            BuildNumber = buildNumber;
        }

        public string BuildNumber { get; }
    }
}
```

Add the following item-group to .csproj file in order to make the property accessible:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="MyNamespace.BuildNumberAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>"$(BuildNumber)"</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Finally in the dockerfile, pass the build argument

```
RUN dotnet publish SomeAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app -p:BuildNumber=$VERSION_NUMBER
```

Note that `VERSION_NUMBER` is set to `$(Build.BuildNumber)` in docker-compose task of TFS build pipeline.

To access this newly added property, do the following:

```
private string ReadBuildNumber()
{
    return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
        .GetCustomAttribute<BuildNumberAttribute>()
        .BuildNumber.Trim('"');
}
```

**The second approach**:
Using "Replaced tokens" task in TFS build pipeline. With this you can set a template in appsettings.json, and the template can be replaced by task. For detailed info, check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379006/net-core-app-how-to-get-build-number-at-runtime)