# Getting release and build numbers from Azure DevOps Release Pipeline to display in website

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I would like to be able to display the release number (*1 in pic)  and the build number (*2 in pic) in Asp.Net MVC Core website - FOR that specific website, which was built and released with Azure DevOps.

So if I check code in for an MVC website, the build and release process kicks in and deploys the website - and now I want the same website to display "Release xxxxx" in the footer.

It could be in a JSON file, an environment variable or something - as long as I can access it from Asp.Net Core, I am happy.

How can that be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be to use a plugin for Azure Devops during build [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens), which replaces strings in a .config file during build/release - and then access those values from the code at runtime.

It is described here in more detail: [.NET Core App - How to get build number at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379006/net-core-app-how-to-get-build-number-at-runtime/42386089)

Answer (score 5):

If you want in the current app that you built and deployed to display the data you can get the values of the variables like each environment variable:

```
var releaseName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Release_ReleaseName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
var buildNumber= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Build_BuildNumber", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

---

If you want to display the data in an external app:

You can get all the release data with [Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). the API for release is [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1
```

You got a big JSON with the release info, including the release name:

```
{
    "id":  205,
    "name":  "Release-93",
```

And in the artifact array, you can get the build id (under `definitionReference.version.name`):

```
"version":  {
              "id":  "1439",
              "name":  "TestVars_20190829.1439..11"
```

So in your Asp.Net MVC Core app just make a GET rest API call and you have all the data.

In addition, you can use the [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) and get the data with `GetRelease()` method:

```
string projectName = "TestProject";
VssConnection connection = Context.Connection;
ReleaseHttpClient releaseClient = connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient>();

List<WebApiRelease> releases = releaseClient.GetReleasesAsync(project: projectName).Result;

int releaseId = releases.FirstOrDefault().Id;

// Show a release
WebApiRelease release = releaseClient.GetReleaseAsync(project: projectName, releaseId: releaseId).Result;
// Now get the release name and build nubmer
```

Comment: I think my question might have been a bit unclear. When the pipeline builds and releases a website, I want that same website to display what build and release version is currently deployed. I edited my question to make that clearer now.

Comment: The code you added gets an environment variable, which is nice, but these variables do not get set (they are empty when I try to access them in the site - and I checked all environment variables in the Azure site using Kudu). 

I am guessing I have to add something to the release process in variables?

Comment: In other words: How do you get the release pipeline to set the environment variables in the azure web app I am deploying to?

Comment: How do you set a normal environment variable in azure web app?

Comment: Through the Azure Portal, under the website => configuration