# How to get Release Number in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In azure release pipeline, each release gets an identifier (Release-1, Release-2 etc) as described in this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746150/getting-release-and-build-numbers-from-azure-devops-release-pipeline-to-display)

In the actual pipeline, I want to read that current release identifier. I have a PowerShell task, in which I'd like to read the current release identifier so that I can inject it into the application.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I finally stumbled upon a clue to help answer that question for my self.

Release identifier is available in "RELEASE_RELEASENAME" environment variable.

It is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch