# Fetch release number from a release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have been trying to access the Release number from a task in a release pipeline, because I need to create a git branch with an unique name, or even a counter would help (I tried $(Rev:rrr) as a counter, but it did not work).

[image: $(Rev:rrr)]

I need this number 95 from the picture below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting release and build numbers from Azure DevOps Release Pipeline to display in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746150/getting-release-and-build-numbers-from-azure-devops-release-pipeline-to-display)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help, I saw that one before posting. I need to access the ID though a bash script when executing git commands.

Comment: AFAICT you should be able to use `$Build_BuildNumber` in Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create a git branch with an unique name

To create a git branch with an unique name in release pipeline, you could try with [classic release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release): `Release.ReleaseId`, which is the identifier of the current release record. By running `git checkout -b "$(Release.ReleaseId)"` in the cmd task you create a git branch with an unique name.

If you just want to use the ID 95 in `Release-95`, try with the method below to add a PowerShell task to run following inline script before the cmd task to get current release name and use `Trim(char[])` method to obtain the ID 95. Use the `task.setvariable` logging command to set `95` as a variable in the PowerShell task.

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/<OrgName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=7.0"
$token="<PAT>"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $base64AuthInfo" }
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $head -Method Get
$Pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$name = $pipeline.name  #get Release-95
Write-host $name 
$ID = $name.Trim("Release-")  #get 95
Write-Host $ID
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NameID]$ID" #set 95 as a variable and use it next task in the same job
```

Finally, use `git checkout -b "$(NameID)"` in the cmd task to create a git branch with an unique name like 95.

[image]

Comment: Using $(Release.ReleaseId) I did not get the 95, but I got an unique number, which is great.