# Setting environment variable in .Net Core Azure DevOps Pipeline so that it's available to Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .Net Core 3.1 Web Api App which is being built with an Azure build pipeline using MSBuild and being deployed to its various environments using Azure Release Pipeline. I want the Git Commit ID to be available to the Web App so I can read it and attach it as a response header on outgoing responses.

I know there's a predefined build variable called **Build.SourceVersion** which gives the commit ID so that's not the issue. Also I'm not questioning how to attach it as a response header as I can find that information online with more research. What is puzzling me is that I don't know how to make this information available once the Web App is deployed so I can read it or how to read it. Should I add a powershell script in the build process to add the environment variable? Is that even the correct place? Should it be instead part of the release pipeline?

Also I know there is a predefined Release variable called **Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceVersion** . How would I have this available as a environment variable to be read in code once app is deployed? How would I read it in code?

Any help is appreciated. Also, I would be happy to provide more details!

Comment: With [the File Transform Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) you can replace values in your appsettings.json (or whatever you name it) with pipeline variables.

Comment: @Crowcoder from their docs it states:  "Only custom variables defined in build and release pipelines are used in substitution. Default and system pipeline variables are excluded.

Here's a list of currently excluded prefixes:

'agent.'
'azure_http_user_agent'
'build.'
'common.'
'release.'
'system.'
'tf_' " so this may not suffice as I would not have access to the commit information via the predefined variables

Comment: You can write it into appsettings.json like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47914309 and then have your web app read the value.